# Как удалить каждый третий элемент с помощью linq?

Tags: запрос, linq, выборка

Можно как-то с помощью linq пропускать, начиная с 1, каждый третий элемент?
т.е. 1, 4, 7...

Вот есть такая выборка, но из неё нужно убрать элементы:

```
var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='xml-feed-table']")[0].Descendants("tr")
                    .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td=> td.InnerHtml).ToList()).Skip(8).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться перегрузкой [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) в которой есть доступ к индексу текущего элемента, и убрать ненужные элементы, например так

```
.Where((el,index)=>index % 3 != 1)
```

Comment: @AlexKrass, так я и не говорил, что нужно не дописывать к существующему. Но формула у тебя какая-то странная

Comment: О, оказывается, есть перегрузка Where с индексом, не знал.

Comment: @VladD, а чего удалил-то? подход имеет право на жизнь, учитывая, что не все методы имеют перегрузку с индексом

Comment: Не, перегрузка с индексом бесконечно лучше.

Comment: @Grundy, да, я просто невнимательно посмотрел на формулу и решение. Вы за 10 секунд успели перехватить мой удаленный комментарий.

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно