# Вернуть null по условию в LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

У меня есть ряд элементов типа `int?`. Допустим такой:

```
int?[] row = new int?[] {0,null,1,2,3,0};
```

Необходимо для всех элементов, которые равны нулю создать некую структуру(Допустим с индексом элемента), остальные отбросить. Логика примерно такая:

```
MyStruct[] ar = row.Select(
            (el, ind) => el == 0 ? new MyStruct {index = ind} : null
        )
```

То есть для всех нулевых элементов создаем структуру, для всех остальных возвращаем `null`. Далее просто отфильтровываем ненулловые элементы, и превращаем все в массив

```
.Where(el => el != null).ToArray();
```

В строке с условием получается ошибка:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between Test.MyStruct and null

Как сделать правильно? Может использовать другой подход? Хочется использовать LINQ а не циклы.

---

Полный текст программы

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    struct MyStruct
    {
        public int index;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int?[] row = new int?[] {0,null,1,2,3,0};

        MyStruct[] ar = row.Select(
                (el, ind) => el == 0 ? new MyStruct {index = ind} : null
            ).Where(el => el != null).ToArray();
    }
}
```

или [тут](http://ideone.com/avbggU)

Comment: Если перенести условие в `Where` и поставить его до `Select`, то потеряется индекс элемента в исходном массиве. Если вытащить структуру в кучу(преобразовать в класс), то получится не очень красиво. Вариант с `dynamic` тоже видится не слишком красивым. Как правильнее?

Comment: А точно нужен struct? class не подойдёт?

Comment: @Zufir Я сперва сделал класс, но делать целый новый файл с описанием целого нового класса, ради всего одного поля `index` мне показалось как-то некрасиво. Лучше уж цикл наверное сделать.

Comment: @Zufir Я думаю можно просто немного поработать над самим запросом. Сам пока не очень силен в ФП, поэтому попросил помощи у сообщества

Comment: Вы потом этот класс/структуру собираетесь куда-то передавать наружу? Или только внутри метода использовать? Если не собираетесь - используйте анонимные классы. Если нужно хранить только одно интовое поле - так получите на  выходе массив `int?`, не нужно для этого городить ни структуры, ни класса :)

Comment: _делать целый новый файл с описанием целого нового класса_ - если в текущем коде поменять ключевое слово struct на class - все заработает

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить каждый третий элемент с помощью linq?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590813/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-linq)

Comment: Что именно должно получиться на выходе? добавь пример результата, который ожидается для массива row

Comment: @Zufir Попробовал избавиться от структуры, с использованием анонимных классов. Дело в том, что сам запрос выполняется в отдельном методе. Поэтому не получается потом использовать поля. Вот тут накидал http://ideone.com/pZes88. Там компилятор ругается на какую-то скобку никак не могу разобрать что не так. В реальной программе структура имеет три поля `int`, так что просто получить массив интов не получится.

Comment: @Grundy Объявить еще класс внутри другого класса - это ведь не слишком хорошо? Мой вопрос не дубликат, там задача совсем другая. На выходе мне нужен массив структур для нулевых элементов, которые содержат в себе некоторую информацию об этих элементах.

Comment: _Объявить еще класс внутри другого класса - это ведь не слишком хорошо_ - не хуже чем объявить еще структуру внутри класса. _На выходе мне нужен массив структур для нулевых элементов, которые содержат в себе некоторую информацию об этих элементах._ - добавь в вопрос конкретный пример массива, который надо получить

Comment: Ругается он у Вас потому что не указан тип параметра `row` в методе `GetRow`.  
Но даже после указания он не выдаст ничего. Потому что `Select` выполняется только когда от него запрашивают результат. Для этого я добавил `ToArray()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать Nullable-структуру:

```
MyStruct?[] ar = row.Select(
    (el, ind) => el == 0 ? (MyStruct?)new MyStruct { index = ind } : null
).Where(el => el!=null).ToArray();
```

Глядя на Ваш код на IdeOne получаем следующее:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public int index;
}
private static MyStruct?[] GetRow(int?[] row)
{
    return row.Select(
            (el, ind) => el == 0 ? (MyStruct?)new MyStruct { index = ind } : null)
                          .Where(el => el != null).ToArray();
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int?[] row = new int?[] { 0, null, 1, 2, 3, 0 };
    var ar = GetRow(row);

    ar.Select(el => { Console.WriteLine(el?.index); return el; }).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(ar.Count());
}
```

http://ideone.com/R0A6lJ

---

На выходе метода GetRow теперь мы получаем структуру [`Nullable<MyStruct>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx). Она имеет два свойства:

- `bool HasValue` - показывает, имеется ли у этого экземпляра значение;
- `MyStructure Value` - содержит само значение (если, конечно, оно есть).

Поэтому напрямую обратиться к полю `index` нельзя. Можно написать `el.Value.index` или воспользоваться новым синтаксисом (начиная, кажется, с C#6 и VS2015) и написать `el?.Index`.

Comment: Да, что-то такое и хотел. Сам догадался написать только `new MyStruct? ...`, но так не работает. По Вашему примеру запрос работает, но я не могу использовать поле `index` дальше в коде. Ошибка MyStruct? не содержит определения для "index" и так далее

Comment: ну вот, nullable struct - это уже практически класс :-)

Comment: @Zufir не знал про `el?.Index`, это действительно решило мою задачу. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Grundy Скажите пожалуйста, а как поступили бы Вы? Вынесли бы таки в отдельный файл?

Comment: @user200141, вариантов куча, и все зависят от того, что с результатом придется делать дальше, куда он пойдет? какие действия с ним будут?  проще всего тут было использовать анонимный класс

Comment: @Grundy Попробую описать задачу. Я решаю задачу коммивояжера на C# этим методом http://galyautdinov.ru/task/zadacha-kommivoyazhera. Там на каждой итерации для матрицы городов нужно считать нулевые оценки(этапы 1.6 - 1.7). В вопросе для примера я привел одномерный массив для простоты, на самом деле работаю с двумерным. По нему я ищу элементы, равные нулю и записываю в структуру - ряд, столбец, и саму вычисленную оценку. Дальнейшее использование сводится к тому, что я выбираю максимальную оценку из всех и использую ее положение(ряд и столбец) для модификации исходной матрицы

Comment: @Grundy Все лежит внутри класса `Matrix`, который содержит в себе всю математику для расчета матриц

Comment: @user200141, это похоже на отдельный вопрос, в который нужно добавить описание самой задачи, твоего решение, и что именно не получается или хотелось бы поменять и почему

Comment: @user200141, В комментариях это будет не удобно обсуждать

Comment: @Grundy Да в принципе у меня получилось сделать как изначально хотел, спасибо Вам за внимание

Answer (score 2):

Проблема, с которой вы столкнулись, заключается в том, что структура не может принимать значение `null`. Решение "в лоб" - использовать Nullable структуру: `MyStruct?`.

Вообще говоря, любой value-тип можно неявно привести к nullable-типу. Проблема в том, что компилятор пока не умеет догадываться о том, что `null` в вашем тернарном операторе - это именно пустой значение nullable-типа, а не объект.

*Для справки: у nullable-типов пустое значение только называется null в c#, на самом деле это вполне определенное значение у существующей структуры, которое не имеет ничего общего с null для ссылочных типов.*

Поэтому, надо привести одну из веток тернарного оператора к `MyStruct?` явно.

Получается как-то так: `row.Select((el, ind) => el == 0 ? (MyStruct?)new MyStruct {index = ind} : null)` или так: `row.Select((el, ind) => el == 0 ? new MyStruct {index = ind} : (MyStruct?)null)`.

Однако, такой трюк изменит тип выражения - а потому надо добавить в конец еще один Select: `.Select(x => x.Value)`.

Все вместе:

```
row.Select((el, ind) => el == 0 ? new MyStruct {index = ind} : (MyStruct?)null).Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.Value)
```

---

Альтернативные варианты:

1. Использование `SelectMany`:

   ```
   row.Select((el, ind) => el == 0 ? new MyStruct[0] : new [] { new MyStruct {index = ind} })
   ```

   Для того чтобы пропустить элемент - возвращает пустой массив. Для того, чтобы вернуть элемент - оборачиваем его в массив из одного элемента. Таким образом, метод `SelectMany` способен заменить `Select` и `Where` одновременно.
2. Использование генератора:

   ```
   IEnumerable<MyStruct> TransformRow(IEnumerable<int?> numbers) {
     var index = 0;
     foreach (var number in numbers) {
       if (number == 0) {
         yield return new MyStruct { index = index };
       }
       index++;
     }
   }

   // ...

   TransformRow(row).ToArray()
   ```

   Этот способ позволяет писать более сложные алгоритмы, чем позволяет linq to objects. И еще он проще в отладке. Недостатком такого способа является его многословность.

Answer (score 1):

Вот ещё вариант, без `MyStruct?`, пользующийся тем, что индекс не бывает отрицательным. Семантически, конечно, не очень чисто, зато просто:

```
int?[] row = new int?[] { 0, null, 1, 2, 3, 0 };
var result = row.Select((v, index) => v == 0 ? index : -1) // индекс хорошего элемента или -1
                .Where(index => index >= 0)                // отбросили плохие
                .Select(idx => new MyStruct() { index = index });
```

Answer (score 0):

Замените `struct` на `class` - и ваш код заработает.

> Я сперва сделал класс, но делать целый новый файл с описанием целого нового класса, ради всего одного поля index мне показалось как-то некрасиво.

Классы не обязательно объявлять в отдельных файлах. Вложенные классы - это вполне нормальный механизм языка, точно такой же как вложенные структуры. Никаких практик, разрешающий вложенные структуры, но при этом запрещающие классы, нет.

Answer (score -1):

Заметьте, как упростилась бы задача, если бы вы захотели использовать цикл. Использование Linq, да и вообще любого средства, должно быть оправдано. Тут же вы усложняете себе задачу, лишь бы использовать Linq.

В таких случаях я бы воспользовался анонимным классом

```
 var ar = row.Select((x, i) => x == 0 ? new {value = x, index = i} : null).Where(x => x != null).ToArray();
```

Дальше этот анонимный класс можно преобразовать в любой необходимый результат через `.Select()`

Comment: То, что я пока плохо знаком с linq - это не проблема linqа, а моя. Linq - прекрасный инструмент, его не глупые люди придумали и внедрили. Задача упростилась бы(Только для меня), а вот мой уровень знаний не подрос. Да и код хуже выглядел бы